# Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate t o a node-set

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am trying to select all nodes with attribute equal to something, I got the error in title.

My Xpath string looks like `//@[id=****]`, anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: No way we can know, without seeing the XML document (or at least the relevant part) and knowing what you are trying to select.

Comment: get the solution. looks like we can use //@id, but to select specific nodes like id=7, I have to use something like //node[@id=7]

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed discussion of the issues with your XPath expression and for several solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath expression probably should be:

```
//*[@id='something']
```

Which means *match all elements whose `id` attributes are equal to `something`, anywhere in the document*.

**EDIT:** If you want the `id` attribute nodes themselves and not their parent elements, you can use:

```
//*[@id='something']/@id
```

Or even better, as @Dimitre Novatchev suggested:

```
//@id[. = 'something']
```

Comment: you are right, thanks! want to know the reason why we can use //@id without the star.

Comment: @user496949, `//@id` would match the `id` attribute nodes themselves instead of their parent elements.

Comment: Ok. Can I get some attribute nodes with id=7 using XPath?

Comment: @user496949 - sure; `//*[@id=7]`

Comment: @Marc Grave: This is not attribute nodes themselves.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Your `//*[@id='something']/@id` it's verbose... Check Dimitre's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to select all nodes with
>   attribute equal to something, I got
>   the error in title.
>
> My Xpath string looks like
>   `//@[id=****]`, anyone know what's
>   wrong?

A lot of issues with this expression:

.1. `//@[some-condition]`  The predicate can only be applied to selected nodes, but `//@` doesn't select any node. `@` is an abbreviation for `attribute::` and this is an unfinished node-test. It is missing the node-type or node-name here.

What would be correct is: `//@*[some-condition]` or `//@attrName[some-condition]`

.2. `id=****` is syntactically invalid, unless **** is a valid XPath expression itself. My guess is that you want to get all attributes with value equal to some known, literal value. In any such case the syntax to use is `id='someLiteral` -- do note the single quotes (they can also be double quotes) surrounding the literal value.

**Solution**:

```
//*[@id='something']
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that have attribute `id` with value `'something'`.

```
//@id[. = 'something']
```

This selects all attributes named `id` in the XML document, whose value is `'something'`.

```
//@*[. = 'something']
```

This selects all attributes in the XML document (regardless of their name), whose value is `'something'`.

Comment: +1 For the right `//@id[. = 'something']` expression and the syntax error explanation.